# Train net using caffe DLL in C++

Tags: c++, dll, linker-errors, caffe

The most recent Windows Branch of caffe (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) provides the option to compile caffe as a DLL.

I found it hard to find example code how to use the DLL in another C++ project as most people use the python interface, which is not a preferred option in my case. Looking at the implementation of the train() method in caffe.cpp, I tried the following to train a net:

```
caffe::SolverParameter solver_param;
caffe::ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie("C:\\path\\to\\solver.prototxt", &solver_param);

Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::GPU);

shared_ptr<caffe::Solver<float>>
  solver(caffe::SolverRegistry<float>::CreateSolver(solver_param));
solver->Solve();
```

Unfortunately, the first line throws a linker error, although I added caffe.lib and specified the path to caffe.lib and caffe.dll in my project properties in VS. Accessing other caffe functions (such as set_mode) works fine.

Apart from the linker error (suggestions to solve it are appreciated!), does the code look plausible to you? Did anyone manage to use caffe functionalities in C++ and is willing to share a code snippet?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ""public: __cdecl caffe::SolverParameter::SolverParameter(void)" (??0SolverParameter@caffe@@QEAA@XZ)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to caffeproto.lib and to libprotobuf.lib to solve dependencies error for this piece of code.

Just diving into caffe so I can't really judge your code. I am looking at this:https://medium.com/@shiyan/caffe-c-helloworld-example-with-memorydata-input-20c692a82a22 and so far found it helpful.

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)